# Unfavoriting a post twice results in it staying a favorite

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-watching, bookmarks

If you go to your favorites, follow the link through to unfavorite on the page, press the browsers back button to return the favorites page, the post is still visible because of the browsers cache, clicking to unfavorite here results the page counter-intuitively becoming a favorite again. Would it be possible to check if the favorite status on the client and server are  in sync before toggling the favorite?

Comment: Back deliberately shows you the state of the page before you left it. The only way I can see to do this would be to async load the questions in to avoid an edge case, introducing pointless lag for the 99.9% of times this doesn't happen

Comment: I was thinking more about a check on state displayed on the client and state on the sever when the user unfavorites on the page.

Comment: Perhaps separate the unfavorite and favorite commands in to two post commands rather than a togle

Comment: Then if out of sync ignore the request

Comment: Either that or don't change the state client so the client side becomes in sync with the server again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty minor, to my knowledge you're the first person to notice it since favorites were introduced.  Furthermore I can think of at least 3 other places where similar disconnects with toggle-able states and history are possible, that I'm fairly certain no one's every reported.

Any "fix" would also be a bit cumbersome, either throwing a message up or *not* toggling... but only on the first click; and would be a special case for favorites.

Not worth changing basically.

Comment: ok its a special case to remember